# write user input to an excel from webpage in zk

Tags: java, excel, zk

I have created a login page in zk framework. When user clicks on save button the input data should be saved to an excel. This is the requirement. Here I have created the login page. but saving data to execl part couldnt do. can anyone help me to export the data to excel? please

Comment: You can use jxl library for all your needs: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxljar.htm there are numerous tutorials on the web: http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html . Also I can't give you an example as it's too broad and too much code to write here. Check tutorials and you should be fine

Comment: Thanks!! surely will check it and let u know the feedback. Thanks once again.

Comment: What about http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/reporting/jasperreport ?

Comment: Hi Axel. have gone through the link provided by you. but my requirement is the user input needs to be saved in an excel.
1. User provides user id , password and gender details (zul page) and the page has the option for "save" button. 
2. When clicks on "Save", user id, password and gender should be exported to excel. like column names as User ID, Password and Gender.

here I have done with the user login zul page. Please help me to export the data to excel